# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED when trying to connect to remote gremlin server (TinkerPop3)

Tags: node.js, cassandra, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

Im using [gremlin-javascript](https://github.com/jbmusso/gremlin-javascript) module to access a remote gremlin server. 
My code in app.js:

```
var gremlin = require('gremlin-client');
var client = gremlin.createClient(8182, 'localhost');
var query = client.stream('g.V()');
query.on('data', function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
query.on('end', function() {
  console.log("All results fetched");
});
```

This works fine and all queries are getting executed. But when i replace 'localhost' with my remote server address - cbtitan.cloudapp.net, its giving back ECONNREFUSED error.

what should i change/do to connect to that remote server? or Should i change any configuration in that remote server ? I'm badly stuck with this problem, please help me out. Thanks in advance.

**gremlin-server.yaml**

```
host: localhost
port: 8182
threadPoolWorker: 1
gremlinPool: 8
scriptEvaluationTimeout: 30000
serializedResponseTimeout: 30000
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.HttpChannelizer
graphs: {
  graph: conf/gremlin-server/titan-berkeleyje-server.properties}
plugins:
  - aurelius.titan
scriptEngines: {
  gremlin-groovy: {
    imports: [java.lang.Math],
    staticImports: [java.lang.Math.PI],
    scripts: [scripts/empty-sample.groovy]},
  nashorn: {
      imports: [java.lang.Math],
      staticImports: [java.lang.Math.PI]}}
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { useMapperFromGraph: graph }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV1d0, config: { useMapperFromGraph: graph }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { useMapperFromGraph: graph }}
processors:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.session.SessionOpProcessor, config: { sessionTimeout: 28800000 }}
metrics: {
  consoleReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  csvReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000, fileName: /tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv},
  jmxReporter: {enabled: true},
  slf4jReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  gangliaReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000, addressingMode: MULTICAST},
  graphiteReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000}}
threadPoolBoss: 1
maxInitialLineLength: 4096
maxHeaderSize: 8192
maxChunkSize: 8192
maxContentLength: 65536
maxAccumulationBufferComponents: 1024
resultIterationBatchSize: 64
writeBufferHighWaterMark: 32768
writeBufferHighWaterMark: 65536
ssl: {
enabled: false}
```

Comment: please post your gremlin server yaml configuration file

Comment: i just updated my question with gremlin-server.yaml file @stephenmallette

Comment: Could there be anything between the client and the remote server that would prevent the ws connection from opening?

Comment: you mean any CORS issues ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 5):

In the `gremlin-server.yaml`, you need to make a couple changes.

You need to update the host. The default is `localhost`, which means you can only connect from a local client. You should either use the IP address of the machine or 0.0.0.0 if you want to listen on all interfaces.

```
host: 0.0.0.0
```

You should be using `WebSocketChannelizer` instead of `HttpChannelizer` with `gremlin-javascript` because it is a WebSocket JavaScript client for TinkerPop3 Gremlin Server.

```
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer
```

Comment: This fixed it for me using titanDB on AWS (the channelizer was already correct), but would be good to understand what is meant by 'host'. It doesn't sound like the property name is describing fully what it's there for. Do you have a link to any (useful) resources? I was having problems getting the gremlin-client js library to connect, but I can't read 'host' in a way that would explain why it seemed to reject client connections.